# Access a UWP class from WPF / .Net Framework project

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have a WPF application created with .Net Framework, however I need to use it to enable / disable the Windows 10 hotspot.

After much searching around, apparently the way to do it is using the [NetworkOperatorTetheringManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.networkoperatortetheringmanager?view=winrt-22621) class.

However, I can't use the Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators or add a reference, presumably because it's part of the UWP SDK and not the standard .NET framework. As I understand it, it would have to be built as a UWP application from the beginning.

Is there any way to do access this functionality?

(I've also come across `WlanHostedNetworkStartUsing()` but this appears to be for the now deprecated netsh hostednetwork rather than the Mobile Hotspot)

Comment: Does my answer work for you？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked for me (as advised on another forum at [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1121533/access-a-uwp-class-from-wpf-net-framework-project.html)

1. Install Windows 10 SDK
2. Add references to

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata[version]\Windows.winmd

and

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`

Then I could do...

```
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
using Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want use UWP API from desktop application that uses .net Framework application or .NET Core 3.x, you just need to install the **Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts** NuGet package. Then you could use the Windows Runtime API after adding the correct namespace.

More information and detailed explanation here: [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#earlier-versions-of-net-install-the-microsoftwindowssdkcontracts-nuget-package).

Comment: This did not work for me - However, I got a different answer over at the social.technet.microft forum- will post below